# problem in coding for layout in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I made one layout in android studio and made a java class (form_view.java) to code it but it is not working.

Here is my java code (form_view.java)

```
public form_view(Activity activity,  int Layoutid){
    this.activity=activity;
    LayoutFormInfo = activity.<LinearLayout>findViewById(R.id.Layoutid);
    init();
}

private void init() {
        e1=LayoutFormInfo.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        e2=LayoutFormInfo.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        e3=LayoutFormInfo.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        b1=LayoutFormInfo.findViewById(R.id.button);
        ch1=LayoutFormInfo.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        e3.setText("hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()== R.id.button){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "21+ only, keep out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

and I include my layout by this code in main activity

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/yes"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="54dp"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="44dp"/>
     <include layout="@layout/ayoutid"
         />
     <include layout="@layout/ayoutid"
         android:id="@+id/Layoutid"/>

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I think java code file is incomplete.

Comment: What's not working?  Describe where its failing and how.  But I will say anything that's being passed an activity and searching for views in it is horribly designed-  you should be passing the view into whatever function that is, not the activity.  It makes me worried about what other issues your code has.

Comment: i believe it does not attack layout to my code for example setOnClickListener not work and when i click button nothing happened.